# Easy way of bruteforcing numbers

Tags: algorithm, set

So I have 10 numbers. Lets say each number represents the skill of an individual. If I were to create 2 teams of 5 , how would i make 2 teams such that the difference of their teams sum is minimal.

Answer (score 2):

With 10 numbers, the easiest way would be to go over all combinations and calculate the difference.

Comment: +1 There are only 252 ways of choosing 5 members from a set with 10 elements. Because of the symmetry, only half of them need to be considered. Just think in terms of picking four other players to go on the same team as player #1. Or get the list using (http://www.mathsisfun.com/combinatorics/combinations-permutations-calculator.html).

Answer (score 1):

This is similar to the [Knapsack problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knapsack_problem): You try to put individuals in one of the teams so that this team's sum is the biggest value not larger than half of the total sum. It would be the same if team size was not restricted.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a crazy idea I came up with.

Time Complexity : **O(N log N)**

1. Sort the numbers.
2. Find the target sum for the set(**T**) that we would like to hit(Sum of all values/2)
3. Let **Q**=set of first 5 numbers in sorted list.**Q** will be our final set , which we will iteratively improve.
4. ```
   for(each element q from last element to first element of Q)
   {
    Find a number p that is not currently used
    which if swapped with the current element q   
    makes the sum closer to T but not more than T.
    Remove q from Q
    Add p to Q
   }
   return Q as best set.
   ```

Though the for loop looks as though it's O(N<sup>2</sup>), one can do binary search to find the number p.So it's O(N*log N)

Disclaimer:I have only described the algorithm.I don't know how to formally prove it.

Comment: Is asymptotic complexity relevant to a problem that has an input size that is both fixed and small?

Comment: I was answering for the general case.in case someone checks it out in the future.Time complexity is provided for concreteness.

Answer (score 0):

Generate all combination of 5 elements. You will have those 5 in a a team and the remaining in the other team. Compare all results and choose the one with the smallest difference. You can create all those combination with 5 `for` loops.

Answer (score 0):

I just tried it out - unfortunately I had to program that permutation thing (function `next`) and call `result.fit` for every element.
Can be done nicer, but for demonstration it should be good enough.

```
var all = [ 3, 4, 5, 8 , 2, 1, 1, 4, 9, 10 ];

function sumArray(a) {
    var asum = 0;
    a.forEach(function(v){ asum += v });
    return asum;
}

var next = function(start, rest, nbr, result) {
    if (nbr < 0) {
        result.fit(start);
        return;
    }
    for (var i = 0; i < rest.length - nbr; ++i) {
        var clone = start.slice(0);
        clone.push(rest[i]);
        next(clone, rest.slice(i + 1), nbr - 1, result);
    }
};

var result = {
    target: sumArray(all) / 2,
    best: [],
    bestfit: Math.pow(2,63),    // really big
    fit: function(a) {
        var asum = sumArray(a);
        var fit = Math.abs(asum - this.target);
        if (fit < this.bestfit) {
            this.bestfit = fit;
            this.best = a;
        }
    }
}

next([], all, all.length / 2, result);
console.log(JSON.stringify(result.best));
```

Answer (score 0):

Same algorithm as most -- compare 126 combinations. Code in Haskell:

```
inv = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]

best (x:xs) (a,b)
  | length a == 5 = [(abs (sum a - sum (x:xs ++ b)),(a,x:xs ++ b))]
  | length b == 5 = [(abs (sum (x:xs ++ a) - sum b),(x:xs ++ a,b))]
  | otherwise     = let s = best xs (x:a,b)
                        s' = best xs (a,x:b)
                    in if fst (head s) < fst (head s') then s
                       else if fst (head s') < fst (head s) then s'
                       else s ++ s'

main = print $ best (tail inv) ([head inv],[])
```

Output:

```
*Main> main
[(1,([9,10,5,2,1],[8,7,6,4,3])),(1,([10,8,6,2,1],[9,7,5,4,3]))
,(1,([9,10,6,2,1],[8,7,5,4,3])),(1,([9,8,7,2,1],[10,6,5,4,3]))
,(1,([10,8,7,2,1],[9,6,5,4,3])),(1,([9,10,4,3,1],[8,7,6,5,2]))
,(1,([10,8,5,3,1],[9,7,6,4,2])),(1,([9,10,5,3,1],[8,7,6,4,2]))
,(1,([10,7,6,3,1],[9,8,5,4,2])),(1,([9,8,6,3,1],[10,7,5,4,2]))
,(1,([10,8,6,3,1],[9,7,5,4,2])),(1,([9,8,7,3,1],[10,6,5,4,2]))
,(1,([10,7,5,4,1],[9,8,6,3,2])),(1,([9,8,5,4,1],[10,7,6,3,2]))
,(1,([10,8,5,4,1],[9,7,6,3,2])),(1,([9,7,6,4,1],[10,8,5,3,2]))
,(1,([10,7,6,4,1],[9,8,5,3,2])),(1,([9,8,6,4,1],[10,7,5,3,2]))
,(1,([8,7,6,5,1],[9,10,4,3,2])),(1,([9,7,6,5,1],[10,8,4,3,2]))]
```

Comment: @user2536650 The language is Haskell.

Answer (score 0):

This is an instance of the [Partition problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_problem), but for your tiny instance testing all combinations should be fast enough.